# InputAccessoryView Not showing - Swift 3 Xcode 8.3 beta (Non storyBoard)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10

I have a message view controller that has an InputAccessoryView. The problem I have is when I pass (user data) to the message controller from my first view controller the InputAccessoryView does not show. Now, when I pass the (user data) to the message controller from the message list controller the InputAccessoryView shows.

Here is the message controller:

```
class MessageViewController: UICollectionViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {    
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = user?.first_name
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    setupKeyboardObservers()
}

lazy var inputContainerView: ChatInputContainerView = {
    let chatInputContainerView = ChatInputContainerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
    chatInputContainerView.newMessageViewController = self
    return chatInputContainerView
}()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return inputContainerView
    }
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder : Bool {
    return true
}

func setupKeyboardObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
}

func handleKeyboardDidShow() {
    if messages.count > 0 {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: messages.count - 1, section: 0)
        collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
}
```

And the message list controller:

```
class MessageViewController: UITableViewController {
    let user = User()
    let newMessageViewController =  NewMessageViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    //Send user data to (newMessageViewController) and show  newMessageViewController view controller
    newMessageViewController.user = user
    newMessageViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true          
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MessageViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Now, this works fine! Here is where the problem starts.
The first view controller has a subview that sends (user data) via delagate to the superview.

```
delegate?.sendBackToDrag(passBackFromBlur: user)
```

Then, the sendBackToDrag method presents blurPopOver view controller.

```
func sendBackToDrag(passBackFromBlur: User) {
    let blurPopOver = BlurPopOver()
    blurPopOver.user = passBackFromBlur as User
    blurPopOver.delegate = self
    blurPopOver.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    present(blurPopOver, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

After the blurPopOver is presented, it sends (user data) back to the first view controller.

```
delegate?.sendBackToFind(passBackToFind: user)
```

When data is passed back via delegate, display message view controller.

```
func sendBackToFind(passBackToFind: User) {
    let newMessageViewController = NewMessageViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    newMessageViewController.user = passBackToFind
    newMessageViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MessageViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Here are the protocols:

```
protocol MessageDelegateDrag {
    func sendBackToDrag(passBackFromBlur: User)
}

protocol MessageDelegateFind {
    func sendBackToFind(passBackToFind: User)
}
```

[image]

Now, it works when I pass the (user data) in like this:

```
    func sendBackToFind(passBackToFind: User) {
    let user = User()
    user.id = "user_id"
    user.first_name = "user_first_name"
    user.last_name = "user_last_name"
    user.profile_image = "user_image_url"

    let newMessageViewController = NewMessageViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    newMessageViewController.user = user
    newMessageViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MessageViewController, animated: true)
}
```

It seems by adding the data as a constant in the sendBackToFind method works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I ended up adding a subview to 1st view controller and push message controller from the subview. Completely removing the popover controller. I am not sure if this is the best solution, but it works!